# Qlik Sense: Sum by Distinct id

Tags: qlikview, qliksense

Generate sample data:

```
SELECT 1 ID1, 1 ID2, 100 Amount FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 1 ID1, 2 ID2, 100 Amount FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 1 ID1, 3 ID2, 100 Amount FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ID1, 1 ID2, 500 Amount FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT 2 ID1, 2 ID2, 500 Amount FROM dual;
```

This is the current output in Qlik Sense:

| ID1 | ID2 | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Totals |  | 1,300 |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 100 |
| 1 | 3 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 500 |
| 2 | 2 | 500 |

The **total amount** should be based on `ID1`, so it should be **600** only.
I tried using this formula to show the `Amount` by following [this answer](https://community.qlik.com/t5/QlikView-App-Dev/Sum-of-Sales-where-ID-is-DISTINCT/m-p/868082/highlight/true#M470056).

```
Sum(Aggr(Sum(DISTINCT Amount), ID1))
```

But the resulting output displays the other amounts as 0 like this:

| ID1 | ID2 | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Totals |  | 600 |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 3 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 | 500 |
| 2 | 2 | 0 |

Expected output:

| ID1 | ID2 | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Totals |  | 600 |
| 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 1 | 2 | 100 |
| 1 | 3 | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 500 |
| 2 | 2 | 500 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you split the data into 2 tables and associate across ID1 then Qlik will do what you want. As a table expression I have no suggestions.

```
INLINE:
load * inline [
ID1,ID2,Amount
1,  1,  100
1,  2,  100
1,  3,  100
2,  1,  500
2,  2,  500];

ID1Amount:
load distinct 
  ID1,
  Amount
resident INLINE;

ID1ID2:
load distinct 
  ID1,
  ID2
resident INLINE; drop table INLINE;
```

[image: Results table]

Comment: Problem solved and I didn't even need to implement a complicated formula. Thank you, great answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a chart expression in the future, you could use this:

```
=Sum(Distinct Total <ID1> Amount)
```

Here's the explanation of the `Total` keyword from [this Qlik Help page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/cloud-services/Subsystems/Hub/Content/Sense_Hub/ChartFunctions/define-aggregation-scope.htm) (see the first row in the table on that page):

> Using the total qualifier inside your aggregation function disregards
> the dimensional value.
>
> The aggregation will be performed on all possible field values.
>
> The TOTAL qualifier may be followed by a list of one or more field
> names within angle brackets. These field names should be a subset of
> the chart dimension variables. In this case, the calculation is made
> disregarding all chart dimension variables except those listed, that
> is, one value is returned for each combination of field values in the
> listed dimension fields. Also, fields that are not currently a
> dimension in a chart may be included in the list. This may be useful
> in the case of group dimensions, where the dimension fields are not
> fixed. Listing all of the variables in the group causes the function
> to work when the drill-down level changes.

[image: Screenshot of Qlik Sense tables comparing the results of using the TOTAL keyword]

Comment: I tried using this and it also works, the formula is not even that complicated. I thought `Sum` and `Total` are the same, turns out they are not. Thank you for this answer.